# validate url in jquery.validate.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have small form :

Following is the script where I am validating the required field for input field which is working perfectly now I want to validate url using jquery.validate.min.js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function() {                                                      
                var container = $('#error');                
                $("#rssform").validate({                            
                    errorContainer: container,
                    errorLabelContainer: $(container),
                    meta: "validate",
                    rules: {                                          
                        feedurl: {
                            required:true                         
                        }                        
                    },
                    messages: {                
                        feedurl: {
                            required:"Please Enter the URL"                            
                        }                                                
                    }

                });

            });
        </script>

<form action="rssindex.php" method="POST" id="rssform">
                    <label>Enter the feed URL&nbsp;</label>         
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO" id="submit"/>
                </form>
```

How can I do this. Any solution?
Thanks

Comment: adding `class='url'` to the input should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jQuery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url)*** provide method to validate url.

Example:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      url: true
    }
  }
});
```

For your code, add `url: true` to the rules.

```
                    feedurl: {
                        required:true,
                        url: true     //here                         
                    }
```